# How to concatenate within 'apply' on a grouped object

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where I wish to edit the information in columns a and b, within groups defined by columns d and e. The procedure to apply to a and b is: set all rows equal to the row where c is a minimum. Columns c, d and e must remain unchanged.

I am using an apply function on a grouped object. I use 'reindex' to change a and b. The difficulty comes with concatenating, "cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object"

This is where I am so far:

```
import pandas as pd

exp = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
                    'b':[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
                    'c':[7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0],
                    'd':['foo','foo','bar','bar']*2,
                    'e':['scen1']*4 + ['scen2']*4})

grouped = exp.groupby(['d','e'], as_index=False)

sorter = 'c'
cols_overwrite = ['a','b']
cols_keep = ['c','d','e']

def wvmexp(group):
    group = group.sort_index(by=sorter, ascending=True)
    group = group.reset_index(drop=True)
    temp = group[cols_keep]
    group = group[cols_overwrite].reindex([0]*len(group))
    group.index = temp.index
    group = pd.concat(['temp','group'], axis=1)
    return group

result = grouped.apply(wvmexp)
```

Why is concatenate failing? Is there a better approach to the one I have taken (i.e. using reindex & concatenate)? Thanks for helping, I realize this is rather specific.

The correct output would be a dataframe like this (sort order and index are not important):

```
exp = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,3,3,5,5,7,7],
                    'b':[1,1,3,3,5,5,7,7],
                    'c':[7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0],
                    'd':['foo','foo','bar','bar']*2,
                    'e':['scen1']*4 + ['scen2']*4})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provided strings to the `concat` function instead of dataframe objects: In the `wvmexp` function do:

```
group = pd.concat([temp, group], axis=1)
```